# How to translate "to manage to do something"?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

In German this would be the verb *zurechtkommen*, it's meaning being very close to *to succeed*, but emphasis being more on the *not failing* part.

Examples in English:

- It was hard to raise two children on her own, but **she managed**.
- You will have to reverse the polarity of the neutron flow. Will **you manage**?
- Help! I need to send a message but **I can't manage** to type letters with hats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first of your three example sentences, I would use *elturniĝi* (this is also the only sentence in which I would use *zurechtkommen* in German). In the other two I would use *sukcesi*.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have anticipated this word construction for the idea that I was looking for. Searching the tekstaro delivers some hits, most of them I would say use the verb _elturniĝi_ in this sense, but not all.

Answer (score 9):

Generally, I would say *sukcesis*, but if in certain contexts you're going for a different nuance, there are other potential options.

- Estis malfacile eduki sola du infanojn, sed ŝi sukcesis.

Benson (CEED) and Wells suggest alternatives such as *helpi al si*. In some of the contexts you gave, both *sukcesi* and *povi trakti* seem to work.

Your final example suggests to me possibilities like *mi ne povas tajpi...* or *mi iel neniam sukcesas tajpi...".

If *sukcesi* seems too easy, you could always clarify with additional words:

- Estis malfacile eduki sola du infanojn, sed kun peno finfine ŝi sukcesis.

Answer (score 7):

I struggle to find a universally applicable translation for *to cope, to manage* (intr.) Maybe *atingi siajn bazajn celojn*, or *tra(ns)en, tra(ns)-* combined with a strenuous verb (*peni, strebi,* etc). Your own negative version is possible: *ne malvenki, ne malsukcesi, eviti malvenkon*.

- *Estis malfacile eduki du infanojn sola, sed ŝi...*

  - *trovis solvojn/rimedojn, transluktis, luktis transen, traklopodis, faris ĉion kio necesis*
  - = found solutions, wrestled through, took the trouble throughout, did all that was necessary etc.
- *Vi devos inversigi la polusecon de la neŭtronfluo.*

  - *Ĉu vi povos? Ĉu tio eblos (por vi)?*
- *Helpu! Mi devas sendi mesaĝon sed...*

  - *mi luktas kun la literoj ĉapelitaj, mi ne scipovas tajpi la literojn ĉapelitajn.*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't searched for one, but off the top of my head, the point of coping/managing is that you're contrasting it with there being literally no way to do something, yes? So further down the scale of confidence from a *sukcesi*/*malsukcesi* contrast I posit would be an *iel*/*neniel* contrast. Slap on the ever-useful -*um*- suffix and I would use something like *ielumi*.

Example:
*Mi ne scias la kielon, sed mi certe ielumos.*
I don't know how, but I'm sure I'll manage.